# Fail to show data using ngTable but no error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to implement the example shown in the official ng-table homepage  [here](http://ng-table.com/#/demo/1-1) as is.

So I copied and pasted to my project and it fails to show any data like below:

[image]

My HTML code is a partial html, loaded with ngRouter:

```
<section class="content">
  <h2>TABLE</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TableCtrl">
    <p><strong>page:</strong>{{tableParams.page()}}</p>
    <p><strong>count per page:</strong>{{tabelParams.count()}}</p>
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
      <tr tr-repeat="user in $data">
        <td data-title="'Name'">{{user.name}}</td>
        <td data-title="'Age'">{{user.age}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

My JS file is:

```
var app = angular.module('pean', ['ngRoute', 'ngTable'])

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
  $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/home'
    }).
    when('/test', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/test',
      controller:'TableCtrl'
    }).
    Url: 'partials/read'
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);

app.controller('TableCtrl', function($scope, ngTableParams){
  var data = [
        {name: "Moroni", age: 50},
        {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
        {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
        {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
        {name: "Enos", age: 34},
        {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
        {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
        {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
        {name: "Enos", age: 34},
        {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
        {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
        {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
        {name: "Enos", age: 34},
        {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
        {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
        {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
        {name: "Enos", age: 34}
    ];
    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
      page:1,
      count:10
    },{
      total:data.length,
      getData:function($defer, params){
        $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() -1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
      }
    });
});
```

There isn't any error message on my chrome consol. So I don't see any reason why this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are having `tr-repeat="user in $data"`instead of

`ng-repeat="user in $data"`

in your code.

try to add your data as

`$scope.data = [...]`

instead of

`var data = [...]`

in your controller and refer it as

`ng-repeat="user in data"`

in your HTML

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just removing tr-repeat and inserting ng-repeat did the job! i must have dozed off while coding... thanks!